# Does the Title and meta description for noindex pages influence SEO ranking in any way for the rest of the indexed pages?

Tags: seo, title, noindex

I have a bunch of pages set on `noindex`. Does the title on these pages influence ranking or SEO factors in any way for the rest of the indexed pages? Or can I leave them using generic title?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it does not influence in ranking, because that pages is not indexed at all, also it does not harmful for your site in some ways, but if you are placing too many noindex tags, then those pages will kept some PageRank or JuicyRank.

Most of webmaster including me using noindex tag on specific directory, that have no quality content for example, list of links([example](https://support.google.com/adsense/topic/19363?hl=en&ref_topic=3373519)), or assets directory for images or some demo codes.

**But, I recommended to use proper title for better User experience, in specific cases, where user land on that pages many times**

Comment: Yes, just to emphasise, the page `title` is a key element in user navigation... displayed on tabs, window titles, page history, bookmarks, etc. If the title is too "generic" it might just be confusing for the user.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't only Google in the web. Many services don't use `noindex`, but do use `title` and `description`. So i would recommend - don't omit them.

As my previous speaker said, there are some entities in the web beside search engines, called user:) they consume titles and descriptions too, i.e. in form of tab or window titles, bookmark or share titles and descriptions. Or would you prefer, that all your pages, which aren't indexed, are called like old good `Untitled Document`?

Comment: Yeah, I have been hearing this "there are other search engines too" thing a lot. Google uses it, Bing uses it..that is enough for me. 99.9% of my ORGANIC traffic comes from these two engines. There are other engines, true, yet it does not concern me or vast majority of webmasters. Perhaps websites targeted for locations where yandex or other country or region specific engines take more action. But not in my case.

Comment: i've upd my answer

Answer (score 1):

noindex means not to index so page content on this page do not matter for SEO. other factor related to webpage like pagespeed, presence of malware etc, bounce rate matters.